# Angular 6 + Ngrx state value update without using action

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I have a simple state :

```
export interface ItemsState{
  items: Item[],
  otherItem: OtherItem,
}

const initialState: ItemsState= {
  items: [],
  otherItem: {} as OtherItem,
}
```

And a selector :

```
const getItemFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<ItemsState>('items');

export const getItemValue= createSelector(
  getItemFeatureState,
  state => state.otherItem,
);
```

In my component I use the selector :

```
 public item: Item  = {} as Item;

 constructor(private itemsStore: Store<fromItem.State>) {
    this.itemsStore.pipe(
      select(fromItem.getItemValue),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
    ).subscribe(item=> this.item = item);
}
```

But when I update this local `Item` by doing something simple like :

```
this.item.value = someValue;
```

`this.item.value` will be updated in ItemsState without using any Actions.

How is that possible ?

Comment: I would say same memory reference, but I don't know enough about the library to tell you that. Could you try with `.subscribe(item=> this.item = { ...item })` just to be sure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the item is sharing the same reference. If you update it, your item in the store will also be updated.

This is NOT what you want. To catch these "mistakes" during development you can use the package [ngrx-store-freeze](https://github.com/brandonroberts/ngrx-store-freeze#readme) to prevent this.

Comment: ok I understand this is bad practice so I will have to correct it. In your oppinion what would be the best way to update only part of a complex object that is in the state, without having to pass the entire object through an action ?

Comment: They only way to do it is via an action, and make the change in the reducer. If your state is complex, perhaps immer can make this easier. https://blog.angularindepth.com/clean-ngrx-reducers-using-immer-7fe4a0d43508